# FTP not working on a specific Wordpress site but working on others (and Filezilla)

Tags: migration, installation, ftp

I have FTP (SFTP) working on Filezilla and also on an "old" Wordpress site (I mean I set up the FTP for that site months ago), but it's not working on a new site.

I'm trying to duplicate that old Wordpress site on a new domain. I've copied all the files and ran the installer OK (I've changed the wp-config.php file before to use a different DB).

But I need the FTP to work inside the new Wordpress site/domain and I've been unable to do it. I've tried the same configuration from Filezilla (indicating the port and without the port, using FTP and SFTP) and nothing works.

Any idea of what could be the issue or how to troubleshoot this?

Also, is there a Wordpress page or file where I can check the FTP settings of my old Wordpress site? (it never asks me for FTP data anymore, it just works).

Thanks!

*Extra info: All sites are on the same DigitalOcean server/droplet, I'm using Apache, SFTP for Filezilla and I've started using SSH recently, but the "old" Wordpress site was configured before using SSH and its FTP settings are still working OK*

Comment: WordPress has no idea what your FTP settings are. FTP settings are set up on the server.

Comment: I know, that's not what I'm asking. When setting up a new site, Wordpress asks me for my FTP settings and I guess it stores that info somewhere (because it never asks for that info again after the initial setup). I want to know if I can check what settings info Wordpress stored for my old website (because maybe that's exactly what I have to use on the new website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer.

The old site was not asking for FTP credentials because the files had the correct owner.

In my case, doing `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html` on the new site, following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ftp-for-wordpress solved it (it stopped asking for FTP details).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the FileZilla username and password are your droplet's root and root password. You may just need to update them.

https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/how-do-i-reset-my-droplets-root-password/,
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ftp-access-to-droplet-i-dont-want-ssh

Comment: The username and password is working perfectly fine in Filezilla and the old site. I just have problems with the new site (probably not related to username/password). But if you think that could really be the problem, please explain why. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm a Plesk and cPanel user, and largely unfamiliar with Digital Ocean. There must be an extra step to accessing a new domain with SFTP (vs FTP). Good luck!